# What is the number after `shutdown /a`?

Tags: windows, command-line, windows-8.1, cmd.exe

I noticed when I tried to abort a shutdown it gave me `Unable to abort the system shutdown because no shutdown was in progress.(1116)`

What's 1116? Also I noticed the command runs with `-a` or `/a` is there a difference?

Comment: No difference in / (which most Windows apps traditionally use) and - (which even some in-built apps accept now).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's simply a code for that particular error:

```
ERROR_NO_SHUTDOWN_IN_PROGRESS

    1116 (0x45C)

    Unable to abort the system shutdown because no shutdown was in progress.
```

Source: [System Error Codes (1000-1299)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681383.aspx)